Keyboard not functional after Windows 10 shutdown
I have a fresh windows 10 (1 week old) and a generic led keyboard.
Whenever I shutdown and boot back up, it lights up but windows doesnt register keystrokes. I have to unplug and replug in the keyboard for it to work.
Things i noticed/tried:

When its functional, there is 5 HID Keyboard Device listed in device manager. When its not functioning, there is only 1 listed.

It works when restarting windows instead of shutdown

It works for bios menu even when it doesnt work for windows

Fast boot is turned off

Usb power saving is turned off in power option/device manager

Edited registry to always enable numlock

Edited registry to change and set 1 to
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\i8042prt\Start

Checked bios menu usb settings in, options are xhci hand off [enabled] and legacy usb support [enabled]

Shutdown pc in the login screen after repluggin the keyboard to save settings or whatever

sfc /scannow

Motherboard is MSI PRO H610M-E

Keyboard is Marvo K616A (no driver provided)


Edit:

I changed 4 HID Keyboard Device to HID-compliant device. The keyboard works, but didnt fix the issue.
If i delete 4 out of 5 of the HID Keyboard Device and keep 1 specific one, the keyboard functions, but does resolve the issue.


I assume this behavior does not happen with a different keyboard?

No, It doesnt happen with an old usb keyboard(no backlight).

Did you install the CPU chipset drivers immediately upon exiting OOBE after the clean install, prior to any other software, drivers, or Windows Updates? If not, it's recommended to clean install Windows again, install the chipset drivers, reboot, configure Windows Update to install all other drivers, run Windows Update, reboot when required and keep repeating until no updates are available, then install software. Not installing the chipset drivers first always results in random, wonky behavior at random and could be the cause, especially if the keyboard has no installable drivers.

i think windows ran its updates before i had a chance to run the msi mobo stuff

If i delete 4 out of 5 of the HID Keyboard Device and keep 1 specific one, the keyboard functions, but does resolve the issue.

The Keyboard is USB 2.0, is the port USB3.0? Maybe try another USB port in the other side, e.g. the back or the front.
It's probably the driver. Windows 10 is usually pretty bad with getting the right drivers for devices. Even if it works to some extent
It doesn't look like they have any downloads for this model anymore:
https://www.marvo-tech.com/
But perhaps you can use Web Archive or contact their support to get the correct drivers.
